# "ESC" key to break loop by changing variable to False in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, text-editor, msvcrt

I have a 2 files in Visual Studio Code. "**main.py**" and "**g_Global.py**". "**g_Global.py**" has this code:

```py
import msvcrt

def key():
  if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() == chr(27).encode():
    u = False
```

in "**main.py**" it has:

```py
import g_Global as g

while x.lower() == 'n' and u == True:
  g.clear()
  print(y)
  y = input('Write a line to add. > ')
  g.key()
  if u == False:
    break
```

...but when I run the code, when I press "esc" nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: does this even run? the code in file main has no `u` defined. Edit: guess this might be a bit of a spoiler alert for you if you're observant. Your mistake is in assuming that the local variable `u` in the `key` function in `gGlobal.py` has any relation whatsoever to the variable `u` in main.py. Just because they have the same name? Nah, that doesn't do it, they're in different namespaces.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh **u** is defined, there is about a few thousand lines of code per file so I didn't bother including the whole thingymajig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access `u` from `key()`, `u` is a local variable. You must add `global u` to the beginning to access the global variable. Even then, variables in one source file **cannot** be modified from another source file. You must combine the two source files (move `key()` to the other source file).

Also, although I'm **not** familiar with `msvcrt`, the documentation says that `getchr` blocks until there is a key to read. So maybe just get rid of the `input()` and `kbhit()`? It might not pick up on escape since it is a special key, though.

Sample: (I can't test since I'm not on MSVC)

```
import msvcrt

while u:
  if msvcrt.getch() == chr(27).encode():
     u = False
```